# Makefiles in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am getting some linking errors during the compilation of C project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.I am getting the following errors:

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CreateRelation referenced in function _main
```

The `CreateRelation` is one of the functions in my project. Following are my questions:

1. I think it is  some dependencies problem.How would I set those dependencies rule in the IDE?
2. could you please tell me, is it always possible to build a project and set the linking rule, how much it is larger, without using makefile?

[EDIT]

```
           relation.h

           void createRelation(LIST);

            mainfile.c
            #include relation.h
            #include xyz.h
             .
             .
             .


            int main(){
            LIST Relation1;
            some codes //
            createRelation(Relation1);
            some code // 

                    }
```

The function `creatRelation()` is defined in the `realation.h.`

EDIT 2

```
          In the function containing main
```

Comment: Show some code. How is `CreateRelation()` declared?  Is it in a header included by the module containing `main()`?   Is the language in question C, C++, or both? Is the module that contains the definition of `CreateRelation()` in the same or a different project?

Comment: **CreateRelation()** is declared in the a header file and that header file is included in the the file containing main function. It is a c project. And the file where the file where the function is defined is in the same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to set the dependencies for the build process.

If the code you are referencing is in a sub-project you can simply tell VS the build-dependencies. You do that by right-clicking on the project and select project dependencies. Then you can check all projects that should be built before this project is being built.

Another nifty feature of VS2010 are Property Sheets. In older versions of VS you had to tell the compiler the include path and the lib-path for every project. Now you can create property sheets for every library you are using and then simply adding them to your project. This way you only have to create a property sheet once and can use it in many projects.

So if the code is in another project that is not a sub-project you have to set the lib-path and include-path via those property sheets. You can display the property sheets used by your project by clicking View->Additional Windows->Property Manager

If you are not referencing to any external projects. This problem is most likely caused by you not implementing a function you declared. So the compiler knows about the function-prototype and doesn't complain but the linker can't find an implementation of the symbol.

I hope that helps

-- edit --

Since you said that the implementation is in the same file as the main-function I would suspect that the signature of the declared and defined function do not match. Are you getting any warnings about implicit function declaration?

Is that a copy-paste error?
CreateRealtion(x); vs. CreateRelation(x);

Comment: Yes I am getting the some number of warnings but not the one you stated here. I am not sure if you understand what I mean to say. In my project, it quite large number of files. The function which is declared is in **relation.h** and it is defined in **realtion.c**. The header file **relation.h** is included in the source file which  contains the main function.

Comment: I assume you meant relation.c

Is this file in the source-code folder of the VS-Project? And does it show up in the project-explorer under source files?

Comment: **relation.c** is a part of the project. It shows in the VS-project project-explorer.

Comment: Wierd. Could you post the signature of the function declared in relation.h and the signature of the function you defined in relation.c?

Comment: Thanks, is the createRelation(LIST) in relation.h spelled as you posted it here? If so you most likely have your error. The linker can't find an implementation of the CreateRelation function because it only has one for createRelation

Comment: @Compuholic let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1097/discussion-between-thetna-and-compuholic)